# Does spring WebClient use a default truststore

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-webclient

I am curious as to how the following code returns a HTTP-200 correct response

```
WebClient.builder().build()
                   .get()
                   .uri("https://www.google.com")
                   .retrieve()
                   .toEntity(String.class)
                   .block();
```

where I have not configured the SSL context, and I am accessing a secured site.

However, when I do the same with the following URIs,

- https://www.cricinfo.com
- https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

I get,

```
Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun 
.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid 
certification path to requested target
```

Is there a default truststore that spring-webclient is using?

Comment: `WebClient` uses default java keystore but it contains all well-known trusted CA. This error typically happens when you are behind some firewall that re-encrypting traffic with it's own certificate. In this case you need to register custom certificate using `keytool` for your JVM or provide custom SSL context for your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SSL context is not provided, it will look for certificate in Java's default truststore(`$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`) and if it doesn't find it there, it will throw exception